# Finding value of variable while use breakpoint Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

I have simple test:

```
func testAdd(){
        let result = calc.evaluate(op: "+", arg1: 2.0, arg2: 9.0)
        print("result - \(result)")
        XCTAssert(result == 11.0, "Calculator operation failed")
    }
```

It does pass, but i try to breakpoint and examine value in console and there is no value, why? Please look at screenshot below:

[image]

When i right click on "result" (on left pane) and select Print Description of "result" output is - `(Double) result = <variable not available>`

But even print function did print that value. Why?

Comment: Welcome to the world of Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Your "result" variable is a temporary local intermediate variable.

If the code was compiled in a Release build (as opposed to a Debug build), then the compiler may have optimized out most intermediate variables, and done the identical computation(s) in a completely different order to get the same result.  So there is no variable with that value to print in the resulting running code.

If you want to see the variable value, try switching to using a Debug build in Build settings.  Or assign the desired variable value to a global variable instantiated in another Swift file (which the Swift compiler is far less likely to optimize out of existence).

Comment: your assumption is interesting but i run test, not an application in debug mode. Test scheme in debug mode.